# Exclude new System.Range in .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net

Apparently, there's a new System.Range in the latest version of .NET. My application has a Range class which is used everywhere. Any way to forcibly exclude the definition of System.Range or do I have to change my code?

Comment: Maybe Ctrl-F for `using System;` and repl with `using System;\r\nusing Range = YourNamespaceThatHoldsRange;`, or rename your range class and propagate the changes through the solution?